# Kindle Cloud Reader can't open this book

Tags: kindle, amazon, kindle-app, send-to-kindle, kindle-cloud-reader

Opening a book on `read.amazon.com` gives this error:

> we're sorry.  Kindle Cloud Reader can't open this book, but you can
>   read it with our free Kindle app.

Is there a work-around?  Perhaps to send to Kindle?

Also, what is the business rationale, from Amazon's perspective, with this incompatibility?  This consumer paid $ to not read on a tablet but Kindle e-reader.

Comment: There is no reason to not let us...

Answer (score 1):

The Kindle Cloud Reader is a Kindle Web App which anables us read Kindle books online.

As my own guess, Amazon use this web app to allow us to read kindle books online, and most of those contents are Kindle manga or comic.

For those long-text kindle eBooks(such as novels), we are limited to use Kindle desktop app or Kindle devices.